# Errors when starting a PowerShell session

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I was using `PowerShell` normally (was using `posh git`, just to mention), and suddenly a weird behavior happened, I tried to restart the session, when I did, I got many errors, which are :

```
Split-Path : The term 'Split-Path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\aymen.daoudi\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\profile.example.ps1:1 char:16
+ Push-Location (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -P ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Split-Path:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Import-Module : The specified module '.\posh-git' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At C:\Users\aymen.daoudi\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\profile.example.ps1:4 char:1
+ Import-Module .\posh-git
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (.\posh-git:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Enable-GitColors : The term 'Enable-GitColors' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\aymen.daoudi\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\profile.example.ps1:26 char:1
+ Enable-GitColors
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-GitColors:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Pop-Location : The term 'Pop-Location' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\aymen.daoudi\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\profile.example.ps1:28 char:1
+ Pop-Location
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Pop-Location:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Start-SshAgent : The term 'Start-SshAgent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\aymen.daoudi\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\profile.example.ps1:30 char:1
+ Start-SshAgent -Quiet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Start-SshAgent:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here's a picture of that :

[image]

I tried to restart the PC, but still have the same problem every time I start a new PowerShell session, I noticed that many commands don't work, what caused this problem ? and what should I do to solve it ?

**Update**

I removed the profiles added by PoshGit, when starting a new session, I don't have any error, but powershell still doesn't recognize commands, for example calling Clear-host, throws lots of errors that I can't understand the cause !

[image]

Comment: What does `$env:PSModulePath` return? Does `dir C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` return any modules (don't need the list, does it return many folders?)?

Comment: `$env:PSModulePath` returns 3 folders, `dir C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` generates an error `CommandNotFoundException` saying  `The term 'Get-ChildItem is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file ...'

Comment: True. My bad. :) Can you browse the folder in Windows Explorer and see if the modules are there? Should be around 57 folders inside. Was `C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` one of the paths in `$env:PSModulePath`?

Comment: @FrodeF. No, `C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` is not one of the paths in `$env:PSModulePath`, but when I check it in File Explorer it contains 65 folders.

Comment: Good. Check out my answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `PSModulePath` system environment varaible is missing `C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` which is the location of all "system"/built-in modules in PowerShell.

Something you've installed (posh git maybe?) has probably messed it up. Add it to the system variable.

The easiest way to do it without PowerShell is using the GUI as described here:
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed posh-git it added some [Powershell profile files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx), basically some .ps1 files executed each time a powershell session starts.

Just remove (or fix) them; from the path in the errors thrown probably they are in `C:\Users\aymen.daoudi\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\...`

Comment: I've been using PoshGit for a long time, this problem just happened suddenly, but I'm going to check anyway

Comment: basic cmdlets corrupted... no idea, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar shell error message when loading my profile after installing `posh-git` ... `profile.example.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`.

This happened to me when I copied over files to my user directory from an older machine - the older *poshgit* [powershell user profiles came along with it](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/).

The fix for me was to rename the old `posh-git` profile from the path below...

#### Original Profile Path

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

#### New Profile Name

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1.notused
```

After `choco uninstall poshgit` and `choco install poshgit` a new profile was created with the right data (*went from 5KB to 1KB in size*).